# GitKraken Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: gtk, gtk3

Hello is this someone has worries under Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with GitKraken to connect with GitHub?, Because on 2 PC freshly installed and updated can not authorize the connection.

I get this error by launching Gitkraken in a terminal

[image: terminal error]

So I search on Google and enter his orders, but it does not solve my problem I always have the same error

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please format your post in a proper way - use plain text instead of images!

Comment: How did you installed GitKraken?

Comment: with the Ubuntu repository

Answer (score 0):

As far I can understand - the messages about Canberra are just a warning.

And real problem caused by missed `snapctl` executable (last line of your console output).
This executable is provided by [`snapd` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=snapctl).

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

Comment: I tried 1 hour ago and I managed to have the window of autenfication yet I did not do anything particiulier, I will try on my other pc